# no known class method for selector valueWithCGRect

Tags: ios, macos, xcode5, cgrect

I'm creating mac application to create a pList file with coordinates for views to be use in iPhone/iPad but I'm getting this error "no known class method for selector valueWithCGRect".

Here is my code:

```
NSMutableArray *locations = [NSMutableArray new];
[locations addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGRect:CGRectMake(50,50,280,323)]];
```

Any of you knows how can I fix this or if is a work around this to fix my mac app.

I'll really appreciate you help.

Comment: Seems strange. Your code worked fine for me. Is this the only place in your code where you used this method?

Comment: How are you going to use the locations array, and how are you going to use the file on iOS?

Comment: The code works just fine in iOS project but I'm creating the pList with a Mac I'm creating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On Mac OS there's `+[NSValue valueWithRect:]`. It takes an `NSRect` but on 64 bit that's just a typedef'd `CGRect`.

Bear in mind that you can't put arbitrary `NSValue`s into a plist.

Comment: if you need to be 32 bit OS X aware also... you can convert a CGRect to an NSRect...

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if you have imported UIKit ?
Just add:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

and the your code should work.